# Assigning a generic type for derived classes from an abstract class with type variables in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, abstract-class, typescript-typings, typescript-generics, typescript-class

I have an abstract class `Base` that accepts a type variable `<T>` to be used within the class. Then I have many derived classes that explicitly define the type, such as `class Derived extends Base<string> {...}`

I want to have a variable (or array of variables) who's type can be any of those derived classes, no matter what `<T>` is. Then I want to be able to use that variable to create new instances of these Derived classes.

Here's some code with what I have tried. From there, I am lost.

[TypeScript Playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=35&pc=78#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgQmgpgHgBUA+BAbwCgEqFRIZ4EA3YZAVxwC4ECBucgX3LkUaDABEcUAJaMcAEwQ4AHhBwA7ORmxh8dKWoDmJCtSYt2CALwIA5AAkcyZAHsEAd2dRkcgIQ2+gsKo6AgAyjiwzhoS0rIKyqoaWrh4aqwAtiCSxpTUzGw4VggAjABMAMwALAFCAPS13AAWUhiNaAgQAJ4ADoUAFF29zgBmCDEy8ggAPh09OCNhEVFy43EAlOTIOIgi6DhgAPoAgkUA2qvyADSLkdGSE3IAunzk9U0tCM4gjFLOrGDITruTwAawwEGczmuIFYiDcUggjQQ6WAaiBcnucSQwR0GFgqIQBm2CBchhoGg68l+-02xN2uIOmC4AzmCwuChmg3mo3CtxWmPka1OjzOzyCon2jIAdN1-o0+uy1nx6ZLMDK5X1ectFS83gRmhg5M59ggAHIAeQIwKgINpOxxkoAwlxtPhUZ0iMLRcqHYdHeqwPKdQg3gAiLlsgUKD5qZyIURSAxqUBbDquLlYFLuoihuoNfUfI0mi1Wjw2u3YiWHMQulKsNQg2NuNSekXWYU+qsHMQBoNRpUhhrh1mjdkIGNxmjoRPJkCpiGzXqZnR4euN5zNnN596G40YEvW21be1dgCitZXekMre94r2h1PvYV-Z4g4Qw6Go6j44wsfj06TFNCgXDNXTwK8jFzV58wNBAi33S1DwrFVDgAMWZCNRldIU2wQDs7wZVCn2DMNMLGb8J3-MAZyAtNF25ZccFDIA)

```
abstract class Base<T> {
    abstract value: T;
}

class Derived extends Base<string> {
    value = 'Hello world!';
}

class SecondDerived extends Base<number> {
    value = 1234;
}

// This has type (typeof Derived | typeof SecondDerived)
let classes_A = [Derived, SecondDerived];

// This obviously works too, but with many derived classes can get long and tedious
let classes_B: (typeof Derived | typeof SecondDerived)[] = [];
classes_B.push(Derived);
classes_B.push(SecondDerived);

// This does NOT work
let classes_C: Base<any>[] = [];
classes_C.push(Derived); // "typeof Derived is not assignable to type Base<any>"

// This does NOT work
let classes_D: Base<unknown>[] = [];
classes_D.push(Derived); // "typeof Derived is not assignable to type Base<unknown>"

// This does NOT work
let classes_E: Base<string>[] = [];
classes_E.push(Derived); // "typeof Derived is not assignable to type Base<string>"

// This does NOT work
let classes_F: (typeof Base)[] = [];
classes_F.push(Derived); // "typeof Derived is not assignable to typeof Base"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is this:

```
let classes: Array<new (...args: any) => Base<any>> = [];
classes.push(Derived); // okay
classes.push(SecondDerived); // okay
```

The element type of the array should be "a constructor of any subtype of `Base<T>` for any `T`".  To say "a constructor of `X`" as a type, you use a [`new`able signature](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/callable#newable), like `new () => X`.  Note that the signature specifies what types and number arguments the constructor expects; if you don't care, then you can use a [rest argument](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/future-javascript/rest-parameters) of type `any` or `any[]`, like `new (...args: any) => X`.

Since the type you're constructing is any subtype of `Base<T>` for any `T` and you presumably don't need to keep track of which, then `Base<any>` is probably good enough. (If not, then please elaborate on a use case for which this doesn't work).

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgQmgpgHgBUA+BAbwCgEqFRIZ4EA3YZAVxwC4ECBucgX3LkUaDABEcUAJaMcAEwQ4AHhBwA7ORmxh8dKWoDmJCtSYt2CALwIA5AAkcyZAHsEAd2dRkcgIQ2+gsKo6AgAyjiwzhoS0rIKyqoaWrh4aqwAtiCSxpTUzGw4VggAjABMAMwALAFCyDiIIug4YFwAglAwAJ6pOG4IABQAlFYk2vjAap1EJNYA2gC6fI06YAB0AA6sYAAW-TEy8oM8CAD0JwjOANbAnUGizRtbu+GR0ZIHcken51c3QghAA)

Comment: This solved it! I do have arguments that I need to enforce as well, but they are the same for each derived class, so this is perfect.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to define type for the constructor:

```
type CtorBase = new () => Base<any>;
```

Now you can use it to hold list of constructors of Base:

```
let classes_C: CtorBase [] = [];
classes_C.push(Derived);
```

Comment: Presumably the intent was for `classes_X` to hold *constructors* and not *instances*, right?

Comment: Thanks for the response, but it doesn't solve this unfortunately. I actually do want to put the class type in these arrays, not an instance of the class. So I did mean to do `classes_C.push(Derived)`

@jcalz yes, I want to hold constructors, not the instances of the class

Comment: ok, changed my edit. didn't quite understand you the first time, sorry :)

Comment: This also solved it. I also like this as I could define multiple types based on the required arguments, and then use all of those.

Thank you!